# Using expressions to get derivative from lambda function

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

Imagine you have a lambda function on input like this

```
Function<double, double> f = x => x*x +2
```

And you want to calc a derivate in point x0. Signature of  resulting method is gonna be:

```
Expression<Function<double, double>> GetDerivative(Expression<Function<double, double>> f)
```

So you get a new expression using this method, compiling it and placing x0 as a parameter you get the result. 
 The formula is

```
df(x0) = (f(x0 + eps) - f(x0)) /eps
```

What I have now is:

```
public static Expression<Func<double, double>> GetDerivative(Expression<Func<double, double>> func)
    {
        var eps = 1e-5;
        var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
        var epsilon = Expression.Constant(eps);
        var secondExpression = Expression.Lambda(func, paramX);
        //var firstExpression = ..
        var expression =  Expression.Divide(Expression.Subtract(firstExpression, secondExpression), epsilon);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(expression, paramX);
    }
```

How to create firstExpression with a parameter (paramX + epsilon)?

Comment: once it is a Func<double,double> that might become a bit impractical... maybe you want Expression<Func<double,double>> and then have a closer look at the expression tree

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 sure. Corrected signatures.

Comment: so your problem is about the math or about how to take apart an expression tree?

Comment: Have you learned anything about building expression trees yet? These expressions are among the simplest to build. Most of it involves `Expression.Add/Subtract/Divide` and `Expression.Call` (`f.Invoke()`, not `f()`), and somewhere, you have to define `eps`. Once you've tried that, refine the question.

Comment: I've tried it, but can't get how to build a lambda with parameter (x + eps). That is the main problem.

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, what works and what doesn't, and what compiler or runtime errors you get when it doesn't. Something that qualifies as a [mcve].

Comment: @madreflection added code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a good start, and the code definitely cleared up some things.

I'm going to build this in steps.  You want to build the expression outward to keep from getting lost in the middle.

First, you want to add `x0` and `eps`.  You already had your `x0` parameter and your epsilon constant.  I'm renaming some things so I'll show them as I have them.

```
ParameterExpression x0Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x0");
ConstantExpression epsilonConstant = Expression.Constant(1e-5);
```

To add them is a simple expression:

```
Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant)
```

Now, you want to pass that to f (that is, `func`).  To do that, you need a few things.  First, you need a delegate.  As an expression, there's no method to target, so you have to compile it.  Then, you have to get the type and its `Invoke` method.  You also need to make the compiled function available as the target of the invocation.

```
Func<double, double> funcInstance = func.Compile();
Type funcType = typeof(Func<double, double>);
System.Reflection.MethodInfo invokeMethod = funcType.GetMethod("Invoke");
ConstantExpression funcConstant = Expression.Constant(funcInstance, typeof(Func<double, double>));
```

Now, you can call it, incorporating the expressions you've already built.

```
Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant))
```

The next expression is the one being subtracted from the first, `f(x0)`.  This one is simpler, of course.  You reuse most of what you've defined thus far.

```
Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, x0Parameter)
```

Now you want to subtract those two expressions.

```
Expression.Subtract(
    Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant)),
    Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, x0Parameter)
    )
```

And finally, you want to divide that by `eps`.

```
Expression.Divide(
    Expression.Subtract(
        Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant)),
        Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, x0Parameter)
        ),
        epsilonConstant
    )
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<double, double>> GetDerivative(Expression<Func<double, double>> func)
{
    ParameterExpression x0Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x0");
    ConstantExpression epsilonConstant = Expression.Constant(1e-5);

    Func<double, double> funcInstance = func.Compile();
    Type funcType = typeof(Func<double, double>);
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo invokeMethod = funcType.GetMethod("Invoke");
    ConstantExpression funcConstant = Expression.Constant(funcInstance, typeof(Func<double, double>));

    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Divide(
        Expression.Subtract(
            Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant)),
            Expression.Call(funcConstant, invokeMethod, x0Parameter)
            ),
            epsilonConstant
        );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(body, x0Parameter);
}
```

**UPDATE:** @ckuri pointed out that you can use `Expression.Invoke` to call `func` without all the reflection.

```
public static Expression<Func<double, double>> GetDerivative(Expression<Func<double, double>> func)
{
    ParameterExpression x0Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x0");
    ConstantExpression epsilonConstant = Expression.Constant(1e-5);

    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Divide(
        Expression.Subtract(
            Expression.Invoke(func, Expression.Add(x0Parameter, epsilonConstant)),
            Expression.Invoke(func, x0Parameter)
            ),
            epsilonConstant
        );

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double>>(body, x0Parameter);
}
```

Back in the real world, define your function, get the derivative function, compile the derivative function to a delegate, and then call the delegate:

```
Expression<Func<double, double>> f = x => x * x + 2;

Expression<Func<double, double>> df = GetDerivative(f);

Func<double, double> dfFunc = df.Compile();

double result = dfFunc(someInput);
```